# Haskell non-exhaustive patterns in recursive listed tuple count

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to count the number of times x comes up in a listed tuple (of Ints). It's only the first Int in the tuple that needs to be located and counted so the other two Int tuples don't really matter. I'm trying a simple recursion count (so that it will add 1 until the list is empty and then it will add 0) but I get a non-exhaustive pattern and I don't understand what pattern is missing to cause it.

```
count :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int 
count x []         = 0
count x [(a,b,c)]
  | x == a              = 1 + (count x [(a,b,c)])
  | otherwise           = count x [(a,b,c)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are only handling the 2 cases where the list of tuples is either empty or has exactly one element (a,b,c). You must include a pattern where your list has more than 1 element. Such a pattern could be `count x ((a,b,c):d)`

In the end it should look something like this:

```
count :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int 
count x []         = 0
count x ((a,b,c):d)
  | x == a              = 1 + (count x d)
  | otherwise           = count x d
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually had something similar but used [] in the count declaration instead of ((a,b,c) : d)

Comment: You could have also used a generic `d` for the array and then use something like fst (first) to get the first  but then you would handle other things.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong pattern. `[(a,b,c)]` only matches a list consisting of exactly *one* 3-tuple. What I believe you meant is this:

```
count :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int 
count x []         = 0
count x ((a,b,c):xs)
  | x == a              = 1 + (count x xs)
  | otherwise           = count x xs
```

Here the `((a,b,c):xs)` pattern matches any non-empty list of 3-tuples, where the first one is `(a,b,c)`. This allows you to use recursion as intended - because `xs` stands for the rest of the list (minus that first 3-tuple).

Note that you can clean this up a little bit by using underscores for the arguments you don't care about:

```
count :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int 
count _ []         = 0
count x ((a,_,_):xs)
  | x == a              = 1 + (count x xs)
  | otherwise           = count x xs
```